# Error trying to execute feature files in Katalon Studio v6.3.3 - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: katalon-studio

Every time I attempt to execute a feature file the below error is thrown. It doesn't matter if it's a new feature file or an existing one. My colleagues are able to execute the exact same tests on their computers. This only occurs when trying to run feature file tests. I'm able to execute other types of tests with Katalon studio. I've tried versions 6.3.2 and 6.3.3 and received the same results. Has anyone seen this before? Based on the error I think it's  failing prior to even getting to execute the code within the feature files but I'm at a loss.

09-09-2019 02:56:05 PM Verification

Elapsed time: 1.000s

Verification FAILED.
Reason:

```
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Keyword runFeatureFile was failed (Root cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Integer
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:82)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.<init>(Runner.java:36)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:42)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:34)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$_runFeatureFile_closure1.doCall(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:76)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$_runFeatureFile_closure1.doCall(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain$runKeyword.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords.runFeatureFile(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:46)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$runFeatureFile$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords.runFeatureFile(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:101)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$runFeatureFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at WSVerification1568055365381.run(WSVerification1568055365381:2)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.runScript(WSVerificationExecutor.java:146)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.doExecute(WSVerificationExecutor.java:140)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.processExecutionPhase(WSVerificationExecutor.java:123)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.accessMainPhase(WSVerificationExecutor.java:115)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.execute(WSVerificationExecutor.java:103)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runFeatureFile(TestCaseMain.java:144)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runFeatureFile$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTempCase1568055363653.run(TempTempCase1568055363653.groovy:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Integer
    ... 27 more
)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:50)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:70)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain$runKeyword.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords.runFeatureFile(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:46)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$runFeatureFile$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords.runFeatureFile(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:101)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$runFeatureFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at WSVerification1568055365381.run(WSVerification1568055365381:2)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.runScript(WSVerificationExecutor.java:146)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.doExecute(WSVerificationExecutor.java:140)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.processExecutionPhase(WSVerificationExecutor.java:123)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.accessMainPhase(WSVerificationExecutor.java:115)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor.execute(WSVerificationExecutor.java:103)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runFeatureFile(TestCaseMain.java:144)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runFeatureFile$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTempCase1568055363653.run(TempTempCase1568055363653.groovy:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Integer
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:82)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.<init>(Runner.java:36)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:42)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:34)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$_runFeatureFile_closure1.doCall(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy:76)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords$_runFeatureFile_closure1.doCall(CucumberBuiltinKeywords.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.runKeyword(KeywordMain.groovy:68)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Integer
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't an answer as to what happened but I deleted the local source code I was using and pulled it back down into a separate location and now I'm able to run the tests. Maybe something got corrupted in the original clone from the repo. Anyway, all is well now.

Comment: Oh yes, the old switch off/ switch on routine. :)